# Unicode triangle spin

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to get the unicode triangle (▵) to spin 360 degrees when the page loads and when the user hovers over the span. I have set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8zRX/2/) explaining what I want.

> ```
> <span id="header">ULTR<span id="triangle">&#9653;</span></span>
> ```

I don't know enough about CSS3 and webkit transformations to make something spin/reset when the page reloads.

An example demo would be Robin Sloan's x on top: robinsloan.com where it says "Hi: I’m Robin Sloan, a writer × media inventor in California." on top.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that i don't know enough CSS3 and webkit
>   transformations, and i don't know how to make something spin/reset
>   when the page reloads.

Well that's what Google is for. Here's how to do it on hover, I'm sure you can find out how to do it on page load:

```
#triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#header:hover #triangle {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W8zRX/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will rotate the triangle when hovering the span:

```
<style type="text/css">
#spinner {
   display:inline-block;
   transition: transform 2s ease 0s;
   transform-origin: 52% 58%;
}
.spin {
   transform: rotate(270deg);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {
   var d = document.getElementById('spinner');
   d.onmouseover = function() {
      d.className = 'spin';
   }
   d.onmouseout = function() {
      d.className = '';
   }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="pageLoad();">
  <span id="spinner">&#9653;</span>
</body>
```